# Shows warning during compiling

Tags: warnings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCl9q.png)
it show warning 
I was suppose to arrange the numbers, In order irrespective of the values, but to move 0 come at last.

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead copy the [relevent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidAlves Why do you think this question should not be tagged C?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't think it should not be tagged C, i just didn't know for sure if its C or C++ to tag it correctly.

Comment: @DavidAlves And so you deleted the C tag. Why?

Comment: I didn't mean to, when I edited the post there was no c tag yet. The owner must have accepted the first editing, and than mine, that had no c tag.

Answer (score 0):

To learn what you are doing wrong you need to read a book in C. Basic one.

I can point some errors and good practices.

1. comparison is done by `==`. so you should use `if(i==0)`
2. After the second for loop you would want to change the value of i to 0. `i=0`.
3. the two for loops should be run upto the point when `i<n` and `j<n`.
4. That `if(a[i]==0)` comparison is not needed.
5. You don't need the while loop here.
6. You can print all of them after the `for-for` looping.
7. Global variables are used but you should have a good reason to use that.
8. Index variables are better if declared and defined locally.
9. what you are trying to do is known as `Bubble sort`.

Even after understanding all this and following this you get error try to run it through debugger, try small value of `n`.

Then if you can't, then ask here.